# how to make system overlay full height

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a system-wide fullscreen overlay layout in my activity code(not xml). The problem is that the layout does not occupy the full height of the screen. There is a gap at the top and bottom. Any idea how to make the layout fit the entire screen height?

```
mFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
mFrameLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
mFrameLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(50);

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.addView(mFrameLayout, params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply Change 'FLAG_FULLSCREEN' to 'MATCH_PARENT'.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Or to remove the system ui(Status & Nav Bar) from view too:

```
    int KitKatFlags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY 
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(KitKatFlags);
```

Comment: I have gone through dozens of SO posts and not one has suggested this. You have no idea the amount of headache you have saved me. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, happy developing!.